# keyStore rsa privateKeyEntry, public key and private key are equals

Tags: android, rsa, keystore, private-key, public-key

I generated  and store RSA key into android keyStore ,
then I generated an AES  key and encrypt that with RSA public-key,  when i want to decrypt encrypted-AES-key i got this error :java.security.InvalidKeyException: Need RSA private or public key

```
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
    Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_MODE, "AndroidOpenSSL");
    output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());
```

after log privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey()
and privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey()

I saw the keys mModulas are equals, anyone has any idea about that?

Comment: You are using an "AndroidKeyStore" key. Try to remove "AndroidOpenSSL". The public modulus of private and public key are the same. This is not the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem solved by removing "AndroidOpenSSL".

Comment: Ok @Monhammad, I posted the solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using keys managed by "AndroidKeyStore" key. Try to remove "AndroidOpenSSL" here

```
 Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_MODE, "AndroidOpenSSL");
```

> after log `privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey()` and `privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey()` I saw the keys mModulas are equals, anyone has any idea about that?

The public modulus of the private key and the public key are the same. This is normal